# Reasons why an advanced alien species might uplift the human species

Tags: aliens, science-fiction

What are the practical reasons advanced for sapient aliens to want to uplift our species to a higher level of intelligence or sapience?

This question is  a reaction to this one. [Reasons an advanced alien race might want to share technology with humanity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/53667/reasons-an-advanced-alien-race-might-want-to-uplift-humanity)
Because that question dealt with technology transfer rather uplifting in its original sense, and as coined by David Brin, of raising the intelligence level of a species to a higher one.

Think of raising the sapience of a sheep dog to that of a human being. The advanced aliens are offering to uplift humans by a similar amount. Why would they do it?

Comment: Will we now be as intelligent as the aliens?

Comment: That is a possible outcome. Sorry I'm not trying to be cute. I realise this could become two questions, One, with uplift but not to the aliens' level, and another where uplift equals the aliens. Simply assume humans are uplifted without worrying about by how much, and consider what the reasons might be.

Comment: In the movie "contact" from 1997, the alien species did it out of shier loneliness, and because they have been "uplifted" by a different species before. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pfOFCUjmEU

Comment: so they can teach us to play their favorite games

Comment: At least one of the answers assumes that empathy (essentially) comes with this.  So what's included in the Uplift?  Just "intelligence" (which is usually very poorly defined)?  Or something more?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I would assume everything that makes a creature a thinking, feeling, aware, and cognitive being. Not something that would be the ultimate at trivia quizzes. "Intelligence" is poorly defined, That's used as a place maker for whatever uplifting uplifts. Empathy, even kindness and sympathy, can be included, but so can cruelty, malice & duplicity. Uplifted humans should be everything we are, only more so, and possibly new things that we aren't.

Comment: Now on Galaxy TV: Milky Way's Next Top Species

Comment: I wonder why we would always assume alien life is smarter than us. What IF we were currently the most intelligent sentient beings. Kind of hypocritical but I would assume they are more intelligent -- I guess it's human nature to believe that there is some being that is greater than them.

Answer (score 25):

Reasons for the uplift:

- **Communication is difficult.** We are simply too stupid for them to communicate with us fully, and some factions don't believe it is fair to take from our planet without an uplift. Likely they will have a "Jane Goodall" type figure who insists that we are intelligent enough to communicate with and insists that  we be uplifted so that deals can be made or that resources shouldn't be taken at all.
- **They think of us as pets** They have limited communication with us and think it would just be the best if we could talk as they do. Sort of a "if dogs could talk situation." Because communication is always measured by the species looking at it.
- **Pure Science** They'll want to do it because they can, because they want to see the results and/or because they've done everything else, and the development of a species is exciting.
- **The way we think is unique** Our method of thinking can advance them, if only we were a little more advanced ourselves. Whether they need it to fight an enemy or advance their society, they see a potential that they need.
- **Because without an uplift they fear war** They believe that we will wage war on them because we are not smart enough to see the bigger picture. They hope that the added intelligence will keep the peace.
- **They need us for a war** They may or may not be warlike, but they are facing a foe which threatens them, and us. We cannot even use their tech because we are not smart enough to do so. They need viable allies and cannon fodder, so they lift us up. They may have even brought the war to our doorstep on purpose so that we would agree.
- **They pity us.** They think of us as children with access to nukes. The uplift is fairly easy for them to accomplish and they want to help.
- **They are paying it forward.** For whatever reason, they were uplifted by another race, and because it is part of their culture, they wish to do the same. For years they have searched, and found that we would benefit the most and it's easiest to do with their tech. In a twist, they can be US, but seeded in another galaxy by another race, and uplifted. We were the control group...
- **The uplift is a sinister method of control** It's a kind of Trojan horse. A gift that also allows them to kill whoever needs culling or control the population in some way.
- **The uplift is actually an organism** It's some kind of parasite or somesuch which wishes to be spread over the entire galaxy. They'd rather we agree. The host race's entire thing is to spread it as far as possible. Benefits outweigh the costs, so they would want us to agree. Could create a hive-mind or ability to process info at a much faster rate.
- **They only eat beings of a certain intelligence** At our current intelligence, we are not sustenance for them. But with just a little more, we are now a delicious source of psychic energy. Like farming, but... more dangerous.
- **Genetics Activate their tech** Their tech can only be run by people with a certain genetic marker. They stole the tech from an ancient civilization (or rediscovered it) and they have the marker which allows them to use the tech. Side effect of making you smarter.
- **Breeding** They have suffered population loss. They have a lot of tech, we have a larger population and a base of genetics. It's simply faster for them to change our genetics so that they can interbreed with us, than it would be for them to build up from scratch. Has the effect of uplifting humanity. It's not how they normally reproduce, but desperate times call for desperate measures. They will offer tech, advancement, and uplift in exchange for keeping them from dying out. If truly desperate, they may not give us any choice in the matter.
- **As a retirement plan**These aliens age differently than us, and concurrently. They are all getting old and know they will soon die. They wish to have uplifted caretakers at the end, and they want a legacy to live beyond them.
- **As part of the puzzle of the universe** What's the answer to life, the universe and everything? These aliens don't know yet, but they know where to find it. They've found ancient clues that lead them to believe various races at various stages of development will hold a piece of the puzzle. If we are lucky, this will result in an uplift. If we are not, it's back to the stone age for us. For extra pathos, we get uplifted and then they figure out the next piece is Cro-mag man--and we get a major downgrade.
- **To build the ultimate intelligence** These aliens value creative and intelligent thinking above all else (this is a variation on **the way we think is unique**) and they wish to build the ultimate intelligence. The only way to do that is to uplift various species and then experiment on them, to find out what makes their thought patterns unique, and then work to combine them into a sort of uber intelligence. Most of the population will simply enjoy the uplift. But a few would be marked for experimentation. Chances that these very smart lab rats will escape are high and could lead to adventure.
- **Belief in their own superiority/making copies of themselves** These aliens believe that they are the very pinnacle of intelligence and genetics. All advanced races should be as they are. When they find a sufficiently advanced civilization, they make them better, by making them like the alien race. They would not ask. People are more intelligent, but are no longer human.
- **To Call Forth Into the Void** In the My Teacher is An Alien series, I do recall an individual being uplifted in order to eventually serve as a kind of radio transmitter in order to contact the alien's people. In this case, the aliens need a whole planet of uplifted people to transmit into the void, where their true masters lie. Initial trials will just reveal an uplift, because a larger population is needed for the effect/transmission to take hold. (As to what the message is when they call--it could be anything: "we tire of this world and immortality, come and kill us please." or "Dinner is served." (We being the dinner) or "Please rescue us from this backward dimension." With the first and last, the aliens would disappear, leaving us with a headache, many questions, and perhaps a permanent uplift.
- **Because the uplift is contagious** Any species they come in contact with that has the correct set of genetics will be uplifted. It's a function of their alien biology. As such, they are very careful about who they actually meet outside of hazmat suits. Either it stops with us, or we gain the same trait of passing the uplift on automatically. It's possible that most species they uplift don't "pass it on" so they may be surprised that we can. In this way, it would take just one or a few of us being uplifted, and it may spread over the planet like a virus. Finding out that we can spread it as well, once they accidently expose a few of us and isolate those individuals before it goes planet-wide, may lead them to want to offer it, because we are more like them than anyone they've encountered.
- **Mars needs moms/dads** They have children in abundance in cycles, but don't have enough individuals to care properly for their children. Automation is cold--they wish to have living caretakers for their children. We have a large population, but we are too primitive to take care care of their offspring. They offer an upgrade so that they can have us care for them in the next cycle.
- **Real Estate/Profit** That's right, I said real estate. These aliens are terraformers bent on making a profit. They'd like to terraform planets nearby (in another solar system) and eventually our solar system. The problem is, the neighborhood is just terrible. All these primitive humans right next door. They offer the uplift so that the property values the next solar system over will make it worthwhile for them and they can sell it to the intellectual elitist aliens. And, they figure that once we get the uplift, we'll want to be customers. This assumes a very busy universe full of customers and other aliens.

Comment: Gasp! An omnibus answer. I feel bit like I've been run over by a bus.  Some of your points could be whole answers in themselves. Particularly some I've only seen here for the first time. Lots of food for thought. Hard to summarize my response except by being dazzled.

Comment: Glad you like. Hasn't seen any upvotes, just all the things I could think of, and if I think of more I will add them.

Comment: Some *are* elaborated in previous answers.

Comment: @JDługosz Yeah, I liked the question and came up with a bunch before I got a chance to post. Even the ones that are similar, I've come at from different angles than the other posters.

Comment: @JDługosz  I added a few more and I think there's plenty more I can come up with... Like I said a4android, when I think of them I will add on...

Comment: Hey, Erin, I upvoted you. More people should do so too. I understand about overlapping. I've been caught with what I thought was a good answer & someone else beat me to it, and I'm only a sliver of difference from their answer. Keep adding more.

Comment: @a4android In this case, it's a list, and there's way more on here then has already been covered. Added a few more.

Comment: @a4android Added one from My Teacher is an Alien, which I had forgotten about...I think perhaps there are an infinite amount of reasons and that I should stop adding. 20 will be my limit because it's getting ridiculous. LOL.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with getting ridiculous. Sometimes that's when the most interesting ideas pop up. However, stop whenever you want to, there's no obligation to go forever. Apparently comics writer Alan Moore makes lists of ideas as a technique to help its creativity. Glad you like the question. My response from WB has been better than I expected and somewhat overwhelmed with the generosity of ideas.

Comment: This is the last of them!

Comment: This is a very good answer, seeing as its so thorough.

Comment: Because... information will spread one way or the other, and taking control of the process allows them to keep tabs on where the humans are at. Not so much a fear of war as just of general messiness in the neighbourhood.

Answer (score 16):

Because accepting the uplift also carries the obligation to offer to uplift others under the same terms.  It’s a [viral licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_license).

The whole thing is a plan to get evolved intelligences, which are generally warlike, irrational in large groups, and spamming the galactic communications, to “grow up” and make the galaxy safe for all.

Uplift isn’t just smarter as in able to solve more problems, but rational and better able to play nice with others.

Comment: Very adult. To quote Tom Lehrer: "Doing well by doing good"

Comment: This answer assumes that intelligence and "niceness" are related, somehow (at least for your definition of Uplift, the author didn't necessarily specify).  This feels like one of those things where, were this true, we should have measurable differences in crime rates between kids and adults or something.

Comment: It's not necessarily corelated. The uplift offered has that result specifically in mind.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse There are studies that show highly intelligent people are better at rationalizing away their bad deeds and plain old criminality. Niceness and smarts don't go together. But JDlugosz's uplift combined them. I'm fine with answers that deal with different versions of uplift. After all, uplift is hypothetical.

Answer (score 12):

Similar to [Rory's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/53873/10429), I asked myself *"Would I uplift my dog?"* - Yes  *"Would I uplift ants?"* - Yes. But why?

And the answer really is *because I could*, and *just to see what would happen*. What would making ants smarter do to their society? We are a species who are very interested in exploring the unknown and learning new things about other species, because it tells us a little more about ourselves. I would suggest that the alien species have this same impulse.

Comment: Yes! I would too. Wanting to find out is more than reason enough.

Comment: I think this is a very plausible answer. One thing I would like to note is that, in this case, uplifting the entire race of dogs or the entire race of ants is quite unlikely. So it would probably be the same for the human race.

Comment: A good point about uplifting entire species. The aliens are very advanced, but they might to leave a population of natural, non-uplifted humans and they might not. Part of their reasons for uplifting us is to make sure no non-uplifted humans remain.

Comment: Good point, the argument I would make would be that the colony of ants have no idea that they are not the only colony.

Answer (score 5):

This looks somewhat related to the anthill theory. But where the alien race would like to lift the "ants" or humans to a level where they could communicate with us.

Why would they do that? Beside being the good guys and being ok with it as Z.Schroeder suggested in his question, they might actually need us.

If the race would be something like eg. predators that uses artifact weapons they looted from other races, but are unable to produce their own. They might need our creative thinking, pattern recognition and ingenuity to help them produce new weapons for their hunts.

A friend of mine told me that the mage in an RPG would buy the largest armor and sharpest steel, and give it to the warrior, because he would need his allegiance and strength to protect the meek body of the spell caster, while he is casting spells. If the aliens are fighting someone else, they might need meat shields capable and stupid enough to fight for almost any reason (humans).

Just two of a large amount of possible reasons.

Comment: You raise interesting points & made me think hard about them. Uplifting would require great skill, creativity  and ingenuity unless Predator-type aliens looted the tech to that from other aliens, then the uplifting aliens will already possess those characteristics. The basic idea of making friends and winning allies in the Great Galactic War has a realpolitik validity to it.

Answer (score 3):

It happened by accident

My initial thought was build ship that is indestructible by a dog, so I did it by building the ship with grey goo. By coincidence this made the ship indestructible to meteors - but it's pure coincidence.

Afterwards it was so good, I decided to entertain my dogs, as I have an opportunity to play with goo, which makes the dogs' existence entertaining on the ship. It also was entertaining to devise new entertainments for them, by playing with grey goo.

Now 10k years later, the descendants of the alpha dog demands I not slurp when I eat.
Probably I should skipped that *space dog scout* game, *find the alien* game, *dog hive mind* game, *find a bone in a planet* game - hm do not recall them all but they were fun times.

Comment: Reminds me of Cat from Red Dwarf.

Answer (score 3):

**Because They Have Reached a Plateau**

Imagine for a moment that you are part of an ancient and extraordinarily long-lived super intelligent race.  You mastered all realms of physics/mathematics/chemistry/biology (etc) to the best of your knowledge over a thousand years ago.  For centuries now you have existed with deep curiosity (the trait that allowed you to reach this point), but very little is left to interest you.

At some point in your intergalactic travels you come across the human species.  They are more advanced than the non-sentient creatures you have found recently, and you can see that they too are curious and always working towards their own self-interest.  There are also billions of them.

An idea sparks!  Your species has not been able to think of any new challenges or unravel any new secrets, and frankly your existence has become soul-sucking and empty.  You will therefore uplift human intelligence, providing twofold benefits:

**1. Perhaps they will think of something you haven't**
Your biology, culture, and experiences long ago became stale, and it is logical to think that another group with a different set may be able to open new avenues for exploration that you had not considered.

**2. It is something to do.**
When you have mastered the secrets of the universe and are bored, something is better than nothing.

And if you want a twist...
Even though you gave them a lot more potential, you still installed a planet-destroying bomb in the planet's core and are preventing them from creating anything that could interfere with it or that would allow them to leave the planet.  Technology be darned, you DO have them surrounded and can monitor them from space after all.  If it all works out, great - let them live.  If they're not helpful... well, you'll get a fireworks show before you cruise off to the next solar system.

Comment: Like the plateau reason, though I'm not sure about the twist. Just a bit too twisty & twist endings in fiction are out of fashion, alas.

Answer (score 3):

As you're well aware minister, the galaxy is 99% filled with spectacularly peaceful civilizations, who long ago in their evolutionary development realised that co-operation was the best way of achieving success not just for the individual, but also the collective. This lead not to just highly co-operative groups of single species, but planets with highly symbiotic lifeforms, with everything from the largest organism down to the smallest bacteria working together for the common good of all life on the planet.

These civilizations never fought an aggressive war in their entire histories, from stepping out the primordial ooze to reaching the stars and beyond. They only wars they've ever fought were defensive ones against the other 0.999% of the galaxy who were primarily made up of poor, desperate and struggling species battling to survive on border worlds at the edge of their respective solar systems Goldilocks zone. Once it was discovered that these wars were mostly about getting just enough food to survive another cycle, the civilized aliens simply started dropping food aid by the ton, the fighting ended pretty quickly, and negotiations on peace and integration began.

The only problem with this 99.999% peaceful utopia of a galaxy, is planet N3752-4A which is recorded in most galactic records as existing in a highly radioactive system of little significance. In reality it a highly habitable Gaia class planet ripe for colonization, called by its inhabitants "Earth".

However due to some form of cosmic evolutionary mishap, all life on the planet is either systematically attempting to kill all other life on the planet, or is so desperate to survive another day on the uninhabitable piece of rock that they live in perpetual hiding and fear of all other life on the planet making co-operation impossible.

Not to even mention the incredibly predatory bacteria and viruses. Compared to bacteria noted throughout the galaxy these killers prompted entire new fields of study into things the locals call "Infections" and "Plagues", which are frankly too disgusting to detail fully in polite conversation, however we'll provide the relevant details to your scientists on request.

The most developed species on the planet appears to have regular wars (We currently put the total in the thousands) with itself for sport, and some of the bigger ones even have sequels. They're currently in the process of developing a super weapon capable of destroying all life on the planet via the steady mass production of carbon dioxide with the intended goal of destroying the planets ecosystem. Major concerns have me noted that the species is currently in an early space age, and that they likely intend to leave the planet for places unknown once they've finished killing off the others. The chief researcher on site even went so far to hypothesize that they may attempt to "Infect" the rest of the galaxy like a "Plague".

We feel it might be in the Galactic interest to accelerate the planets evolution to the point were its inhabitants are capable of co-operation before intervention becomes impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Because however advanced they are, they still feel like the universe is a humongous, empty and cold sad place, and it's a low cost for them to uplift us and get the help of 8 billion new wet computers in their existential quest to make the universe less senseless

Answer (score 2):

Uplift is an economic harvesting technique.  Our planet has many wonderful things which the aliens want.  Our history, our culture, our art and our literature are all worth a fortune on the galactic market.

But it is illegal to trade with immature species.  Much like our own laws which make contracts signed by children invalid, the galaxy sees trade with non-upgraded species as potentially exploitative, therefore illegal.

They uplift us so that they can invite us into their economy.

Answer (score 1):

Many humans would, if it were at all possible, uplift their cats and dogs. Because they love them and care for them, and would like to be able to communicate more fully - to have them as more of a companion.

I know I'd like my cat to be much smarter - so she could understand me when I ask her not to bring me more "presents"...

So would aliens want to uplift us because they care for us, or are annoyed by us being stupid enough to make a mess of our world? Maybe.

Comment: As a dog owner I know exactly how you feel. There's no reason why advanced aliens might love and care for humans too, and uplift us for the same reason.

Comment: Wouldn't you be worried that your cat might find a job and move out of the house?

Comment: Lol. Only in the same way I expect my kids to do exactly that

Comment: I'd point out that intelligent breeds of dogs, not to mention more intelligent creatures like pigs and monkeys, are known for being pains as pets because of their ability to get around human attempts to limit their actions.

Comment: @prosfilaes - and the other side of the coin is that unintelligent breeds of animals are known for being pains as pets as they can be too stupid. Some folks love intelligent animals, others want dumb animals. Everyone is different

Answer (score 1):

Childhood's End by Arthur C Clark posits and interesting notion: that uplifting is how they reproduce. By elevating humanity to their non-corporeal state, they add our potential to their own.

There is another series where uplifting is basically what races do to get prestige and power in the galactic community. No species would let any one other species get too powerful, so a compromise is to uplift a species that serves you until they grow up enough to negotiate or fight their way free of you. For the life of me I can't remember what the series is called, but in it humans had uplifted apes and dolphins. The book I read was about a crew of humans, dolphins, and one ape that crashed on an ocean world.

Comment: It's the Uplift books by David Brin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uplift_Universe :) The books have a _lot_ of holes in them but some decent writing/ideas.

Comment: The book with the crash on an ocean planet is David Brin's STARTIDE RISING (1983)

Answer (score 1):

In [*A Deepness in the Sky*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Deepness_in_the_Sky), the alien culture--in its current state--wasn't useful to the humans in orbit around their world.

Comment: So uplifting is done in the hope that an alien culture, in this case ours, would become useful. That's a nice idea. Would it be possible for you to expand this notion to suggest ways our culture could become useful?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you had traversed the know universe, then the unknown universe, then made a pit stop in the "kind of known but not that well" universe when your super advanced star ship, full of massively intellectual comrades, stumbles upon a signal coming from the third mud ball adjacent to a tiny star.

You decide to investigate. It takes a few days to decipher the language and over the course of the next few weeks you begin to realise that there are people who actually *want* Donald Trump to be president. After several discussions and debates you have decided that blowing the planet out of existence for this lack of intellect isn't quite the legacy you want to leave behind. The only option left would be to make the people more intelligent so they have a chance at realising how stupid they were to let themselves get so close to extinction.

Of course there is always that one person on a star ship of this kind that believes Donald Trump should also be uplifted, naturally leading to the construction of a wall around the milky way that your advanced race now has to pay for!

Comment: There's always a price. Those Andromedans are drug-dealing low-lifeforms who we have to keep out of our galaxy. Welcome to Worldbuilding SE, Paul, if this is your first answer, then glad to ahve you onboard.

Answer (score 1):

**Religion**

Why every one thinks advance aliens as non-believer species? They could have a religious duty to share the wisdom and technology with other races. In the end, they will ask us to believe in what they believe and with their gifts, we might just say yes.

Bring light to those who have none.
Bring wisdom to the fool for you have some.
Bestow them the intellect that is given to you,
So that they would understand the Collective Sun.

Comment: We could call this idea the missionary position. However, levity aside there's no reason why advanced sapients might have abandoned religion or concepts of spiritual wisdom. Therefore, it's a very plausible reason.

Answer (score 1):

Because all life that clings to the notion of exploration or even building advanced star ships that can travel light years of distance has something in common. It's safe to assume that on some basic level we must have something in common, such as the want or need to know something.

Helping us would in turn help them, unless their agenda is different. Then they could simply avoid us altogether or take us out with a Deathstar - whichever works.

I don't think the spirituality factor works on a stellar scale, a species so advanced would have transcended the principles of words and thoughts. To them the idea of spiritual reasoning would seem just as alien as the resounding choirs of church and space baptisms.

Answer (score 0):

Spirituality. They believe in a natural progression of all sapient beings towards an ultimate level. Humans are on a lower-to-middle level right now - quite intelligent, but obviously with much room for improvement (just look at all the wars, crime, greed,...). Part of the uplifting would be an immanent wisdom to end wars and poverty, and a deep understanding of the natural progression of sapient beings. Freed from these burdens and equipped with far more powerful minds, earth would join the other advanced species on their journey to the ultimate level, uplifting others species as well when they are found.

Comment: But haven't the aliens contradicted themselves by believing in a _natural_ progression, then using  _unnatural_ means to progress other species?

Comment: I've to improve my wording. With "natural" I ment something like "as predefined by nature" or "destiny of all beeings".

Comment: I'm glad you brought spiritual uplift into the picture. This helps widen and deepen the possibilities on what uplift could be, Spirituality is often overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried recruiting decent engineers lately? In order to maintain the technology of a galactic empire, you need lots of engineers. Uplift a species sufficiently and you won't run out of new talent.

Comment: Instead of shifting the problem of finding engineers to other to produce and suppy them, it's probably time to make order in own house?

Answer (score 0):

Same reason you build schools in third world countries.

Empathy.

For just pennies a day you can help earthlings free themselves from the ravages of poverty, war, and daytime talk shows.

Or maybe they just want us to live long enough to see how Game of Thrones ends.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever give kalashnikovs to monkeys. It would be very funny, I know, but what if they chase you down to hell?

Every civilization should have evolved from basic forms of lifes and competition is the essential way to push evolution forward. Those aliens should be smart enough to not raise our technological level up to where we could pose a threat.

Someone above has mentioned a "proxy war strategy". I like that idea.

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question. Uplifting does not involve giving the newly sapient species equivalent technology.

Comment: Oh you're right, thanks. Then I'd say "to not feel alone" at an intellectual or spiritual level.

Comment: Also I would say thank you for your honest critic/advice, wich helps to uplift me, and encourages me to make greater contributions ;)

Comment: Glad to see a question about uplifting humans has actually uplifted a human. Hi and welcome to Worldbuilding SE, user2807674, looking forward to more contributions from you.